# How can I set a font in a bash --x11 script?

Tags: bash, x11, rstudio

```
#!/bin/bash

module load rstudio

srun -p interactive -N 1 --cpus-per-task=8 --time=4:00:00 --mem=80gb --job-name="RS_job"  --x11 rstudio
```

A simple bash to bring up an interactive node but the default x11 font has these fi/fl ligatures that offset the cursor. Can I override the x11 font?

Answer (score 0):

In X11, fonts come from the local machine, not the remote machine.  Make sure you have the correct fonts installed locally.

Also, there may be options within rstudio to select fonts that you may need to either adjust, or make sure the fonts set there exist on your local machine.

Comment: So would I just create a fonts folder in /.local, copy some font files, and set the XDG path to that location?

Comment: Depending on your local X11 server, there may be multiple options.  You could set up a  font server and add it to your font path.  It may support adding random directories to your font path, or it may require they be subdirectories of a specific directory.  You probably have to index the font directory before the X server will accept it.

Comment: I tried setting XDG_FONTS_DIR="usr/share/fonts" in /.config but no luck there

Comment: You would set font path with the `xset` command.  Note that this is probably something you should run manually locally or in a local start up config file, not in your job file.  Also, you should check the current setting before you change it or you might end up with no fonts, which might make things difficult to read.

Comment: I just created a /.fonts folder, copied a few fonts from usr/share/fonts, and set the XDG path to $HOME/.fonts. Seems to have worked.